Unitarian sock puppets?
I've been seeing a lot of "questions" that seem to be actually intended to oppose the divinity of Jesus, rather than seriously asking.  Different names, and always answered and/or commented on to argue against the divinity of Jesus.  These also have different accounts, and some of them "new contributor."
I have nothing against someone who honestly believes something saying so, but if a "question" is really a ploy to get sock puppets in, …

Motives behind asking questions can only be a matter of speculation. Yet even if a motive is suspect, the question itself may remain valid, in its own right. And there are very many people in the world today who genuinely object to the orthodoxly Christian doctrine of the Trinity. They should not be prevented from asking challenging questions about that, if they can put their question in a polite way, with researched evidence for why the question should be asked.
Of course, on Stack Hub, questions challenging the Trinity doctrine abound, and many being put forward are just rehashed repeats of what has already been dealt with before. If an OP has not done homework on that point, the question may well be closed as being a repeat.
As for soc accounts, well that is something the Moderators are alert to and seek to prevent. Proving an account to be in that category is not easy, of course. You have warrant for being suspicious about some recent ones.
Yet it needs to be pointed out that the Stack Biblical Hermeneutics sits is not a Christian site. Atheists and people from different world faiths are just as entitled to post a legitimate question as are Christians: whatever their motives. If some are operating soc accounts, that is not legitimate, and they risk being debarred from the site - perhaps even permanently. That won't prevent determined individuals from setting up more soc accounts, unfortunately. So, this is just something that can crop up, but if anybody has possible evidence of this, I'm sure the Moderators would be glad to consider that.
The other point you mention, that of arguing in comments, is a different matter which may have nothing to do with soc accounts. One individual with one account can be quite antagonistic in their many comments, so abusing the comments function. But we have an option for reporting such hostile commenting.

Like I said, I don't object to an honest question; merely to those that are dishonestly disguising their proselytizing.  And I have no quarrel with opinions I disagree with—in answers or comments.
